# send php post variable to url using javascript when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, php, get, onclick, openurl

I have a php page which gets $page and $user using post method, I also have a button that i want, to open a URL in the same window using $page and $user variables when clicked, to use them with $_GET[] function.
i want my URL be like:

```
http://www.test.com/test.php?page=$page&user=$user
```

my code is like this:

```html
<?php
$page=$POST_['page'];
$user=$POST_['user'];
<?


<html>
<head>

function openurl() {
var user=<?php echo "$user";?>;
var page=<?php echo "$page";?>;
open('www.test.com/test.php?page='+page'&user='+user,'_self');

}

</head>
<body>

<button onclick="openurl()" type="button">open url</button>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: If you want GET, then `<a href="http://www.test.com/test.php?page=$page&user=$user" class="button">Open URL</a>` with the appropriate CSS is the best way

Comment: I assume here's the mistake,<?php
$page=$_POST['page'];
$user=$_POST['user'];
?>

Comment: `$POST_['page']` is wrong, use either `$_POST['page']` for only post variable or  `$_REQUEST['page']` for both POST and GET variable

Comment: ( I assume here's the mistake,<?php $page=$_POST['page']; $user=$_POST['user']; ?> )  but what is the right one? i need to put data from $page in to java variable.

Comment: it was typing mistake Bart, i think the problem is data are not going into java var from php variable, as pundit said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for scripting at all

**If you want GET:**

```
<?php
$page=$GET_['page']; // should be sanitized and you can use REQUEST for either 
$user=$GET_['user'];
$parm = "page=".$page."&user=".$user;
?>
<a href="http://www.test.com/test.php?<?php echo $parm; ?>" class="button">Open URL</a>
```

**If you need to post:**

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="page" value="<?php echo $page; ?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="user" value="<?php echo $user; ?>"/>
<input type="submit" value="Open URL" />
</form>
```

Comment: good idea, but when i click it the url become like "http://www.test.com/test.php?<? echo $parm ?>"

Comment: Then you need <?php instead of just <?

Comment: Thank you mplungjan <?php was the idea, it is working now, thanks a lot man.

Comment: another question, in post methode i think there is some problem with value="<$php echo $page; ?> cause it puts <$php echo $page; ?> in the text box. how can i fix it?

Comment: Your page has to be rendered by the pho engine so it must end on .php and be served from a server. View source and the must be no <?php ... ?> anywhere

Comment: i am testing with easyphp and same result.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can **create a form** and via Javascript just run YOURFORMNAME.submit();
2. Use **href in javaScript** to move to another location:

   location.href="www.test.com/test.php?page='+page'&user='+user"

Comment: thanks for your answer federico but i dont want to have form i can only have a button there in my page. i think the problem is data are not going into java var from php variable

Answer (score 0):

Change these lines:

```
<?php
$page=$POST_['page']; 
$user=$POST_['user']; 
<?

....

var user=<?php echo "$user";?>; 
var page=<?php echo "$page";?>; 
open('www.test.com/test.php?page='+page'&user='+user,'_self');
```

to this:

```
<?php
$page=$_POST['page']; //incorrect $_POST declaration
$user=$_POST['user']; //incorrect $_POST declaration
?> //php tag incorrectly closed

....

var user=<?php echo $user;?>; //echoing a variable not string (no need for quotes)
var page=<?php echo $page;?>; // echoing a variable not string (no need for quotes)
open('www.test.com/test.php?page='+page+'&user='+user,'_self'); // link was broken, forget to put '+' after page variable in link.
```